# how to make global variable in flutter

Tags: flutter

i wanted global variable to use in any function
so i added code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
Future<Database> dataBase;
```

like this. so i thought dataBase became global-variable and store the value the whole time. but it didn't. after i use dataBase variable

```dart
createDB() async {
  dataBase = openDatabase(join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'data.db');
}
```

like this
 
and i would have use the dataBase in others function

```dart
getData() async {
  final Database db = await dataBase;
}
```

but when i runned the app dataBase in `getData() function` was null why dataBase was null?
and how can i make global variable?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `Future<Database> dataBase;` will not initialize `dataBase` to a future but `null`, it is equivalent to `Future<Database> dataBase = null;`.

Most likely your call in `getData()` happens before `createDB()` will have the change to set the `Future`.

A common singelton pattern in dart is using a top level getter function like this:

```dart
Future<Database> _db;

Future<Database> getDataBase() async {
  _db = _db ?? openDatabase(join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'data.db');
  return _db;
}
```

and then in `getData()`:

```dart
getData() async {
  final Database db = await getDataBase();
}
```

Comment: is there only that way? i mean when i make a int value like i asked and run the function to give a value. however after function run the int value became null again i think in these case definitly function ran